# Reorder cms links in the left column

Tags: module, content-management-system, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop site which includes few CMS pages. I have added these pages to Left Column in CMS BLock

BO->Modules->CMS Block ->configure->Left Column

I want to rearrange the cms page links in this part. Does anyone know how i can do it.

I checked the Prestashop forums and most answers were related to footer links not the leftColumns links like the following 
[cms block link](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/22646-module-blocklink-blockfooterlink-sortable-links-cms-links/)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to Back office -> cms ->positions . click on positions up and down arrow key and re arrange the all the cms pages. This solution works for me.